# VOLTTRON Actuator agent failure message but it appears to be working just fine

Tags: volttron

I'm using the [actuator agent](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/stable/volttron-api/services/ActuatorAgent/actuator.agent.html) `get_multiple_points` with VOLTTRON 8.1.3 to make about 30 BACnet read requests of sensors with:

```
zone_setpoints_data = self.vip.rpc.call('platform.actuator', 'get_multiple_points', actuator_get_this_data).get(timeout=300)
```

And I notice this debug message:

```
2022-06-09 19:55:21,927 (loadshedagent-0.1 2930461) __main__ DEBUG: [Simple DR Agent INFO] - ACTUATOR SCHEDULE EVENT SUCESS {'result': 'FAILURE', 'data': {}, 'info': 'REQUEST_CONFLICTS_WITH_SELF'}
```

***But I have the data, like it appears to be working just fine*** in addition to the 1 minute interval scrape all BACnet devices inside the building. Anything to worry about or should I make some sort of adjustment?

***EDIT***
Code snip for scheduling the actuator below. Am I scheduling the actuator agent wrong with the `_now,str_start,_end,str_end` on 30 devices for `get_multiple_points`? Should I be adjusting this `td(seconds=10)` uniquely to space out the call for each device?

```
# create start and end timestamps for actuator agent scheduling
_now = get_aware_utc_now()
str_start = format_timestamp(_now)
_end = _now + td(seconds=10)
str_end = format_timestamp(_end)


actuator_schedule_request = []
for group in self.nested_group_map.values():
    for device_address in group.values():
        device = '/'.join([self.building_topic, str(device_address)])
        actuator_schedule_request.append([device, str_start, str_end])

# use actuator agent to get all zone temperature setpoint data
result = self.vip.rpc.call('platform.actuator', 'request_new_schedule', self.core.identity, 'my_schedule', 'HIGH', actuator_schedule_request).get(timeout=90)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that getting points won't cause that debug message.  What the message you are seeing comes from https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/releases-8.x/driver-framework/actuator/actuator-agent.html?highlight=REQUEST_CONFLICTS_WITH_SELF#task-schedule-failures

So it appears that somewhere your schedules are overlapping.  But the call to get_multiple_points should not have anything to do with this error.

Comment: Hi Craig, I added in an edit for how I am scheduling the actuator agent, is this wrong?